# My Actions on Google SDK users can not access my test app?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, beta-testing

I went through the steps given in the instructions when you use the Share icon from the AoG simulator to add testers:

- Added them to the IAM section of the Google Console with the Project -> Viewer Roll, using their E-mail
- Turned on Voice & Audio Activity
- Sent them (me, alternate account) the Share link
- Clicked on the Share Link sent to my alternate Gmail account and I definitely saw the "Testing Enabled" notification appear briefly.
- I also tried using the Simulator from a Private/Incognito window, a solution I saw on Stack Overflow.

However, whenever I try to use the invocation phrase, which definitely works for me from my developer account, I get the error "Sorry, that action is not available in simulation".

Can anyone tell me how I can add a tester successfully that can actually access my test app?

Answer (score 1):

While investigating my issue from the Google Simulator page for Actions on Google SDK app testing, I clicked on the Speaker icon under **Surface** 
 section while using the Google Account of one of my test users, which belongs to a client that I contract for.  Then I saw a dialogue box instructing me to change/check the following Google Account settings from this page:

https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols

I needed to:

- Turn on **Web & App Activity**
- Check the checkbox to enable the setting titled **Include Chrome browsing history and activity from websites and apps that use Google services**.
- Turn on **Voice & Audio Activity**
- Turn on **Device Information**

**Voice & Audio Activity** was already on, but **Web & App Activity** was not.  I was able to turn on **Web & App Activity** but I could not check the checkbox for *Chrome browsing history & activity* because of a global account restriction against doing that put in place by the client's Google Account administrator.  This appears to be the problem that is causing me to get the error message indicating that the testing of a Draft version of my app is not available from the Simulator.